# Detecting users timezone and changing it in a countdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, countdown

I need to detect and change the timezone of a user in my countdown. var deadline is my variable where I specify the date and timezone.

This is my javascript code:

```
    function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = 'December 31 2015 00:00:50 UTC+0200';
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript) answer for getting the time zone of the user and compare with your time zone and decrement it.

Comment: Yes ok, but how do I decrement it in my variable? Can I just do `var deadline = ('December 31 2015 00:00:50 UTC+0200') - offset;`? This wouldn't work, would it?